# How can i sync data of codeigniter database with wordpress database ? Is there any API available for this?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, codeigniter

**Requirement :**

I have table 'user' in **CodeIgniter** database as well as in **WordPress** database. If i am inserting data into 'user' table of **CodeIgniter** database,insert the same into 'user' table of **WordPress**.

Comment: why would you want to do that !?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by providing an **Web API** at wordpress or codeigniter level that provide you the required function to add a new user when a user is added in the system.

**Note:** Keep in mind that it is difficult to maintain the same data at two different places. In case of any update you have to maintain it on both side.